# Проблема с прокруткой toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть разметка

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`ViewPager` отображает два фрагмента с `ListView`. По идее `toolbar` должен скроллится(скрывается) при прокручивании `ListView` но этого нет. 
В чем проблема. Насколько я знаю для этого не нужно никакого дополнительного кода.

Comment: из дефолтных виджетов, кажется, только `RecyclerView` и `NestedScrollView` реализует класс `Behavoir`/ Остальным надо костылить что то чтоб работало.

Comment: Это я хотел узнать, можете дать ссылку на реализацию с ListView. И вообще чем плох RecyclerView. Может его использовать?

Comment: Нет никаких причин, чтобы не использовать `RecyclerView` в данной задаче. Он "плох" только тем, что необходимо самому реализовать слушатели событий в айтемах.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
у ListView а не у ViewPager

Comment: Попробовал, теперь ListView отображается с самого верху, а toolbar и tabs сверху него прозрачные, только надписи видно.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare простой пример android.support.design

Comment: У меня все так и есть, за исключением того, что у меня ListView, а везде в примерах RecyclerView. Может проблема в этом?

Comment: Да скорее всего проблема связана с ListView. Вот здесь вроде есть решение  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612453/scrollingviewbehavior-for-listview

Comment: Добавил if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true); }. Ничего не происходит

Comment: Вообщем будет работать только с RecyclerView или NestedScrollView для всего остального надо костыли придумывать. Я думаю что ListView можно отодвинуть на второй план и начать использовать RecyclerView.

Comment: Так и сделаю, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Во фрагменте где есть ListView

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Хотите сказать, что вы добавили ToolBar и listView и думаете, что если вы скролите ListView, то ToolBar должен пропадать? Если да, то это бред. В данной ситуации необходимо отслеживать скроллинг ListView сверху-вниз и отловив это событие совершать действие по скрыванию ToolBar, конкретного метода не подскажу, всё зависит от реализации